# arrays duplicates javascript

Tags: javascript

This code is supposed to return the second largest number in the array. However I notice that this code does not work if there are duplicate elements in the array. It returns the largest number as the second largest number when I set the array equal to [2, 3, 6, 6, 5]. It is supposed to return 5 as the second largest and the 6 is the first largest.

I added portion of code in the else if to see if I can delete a duplicate but it didn't work it is still returning 6 instead of 5.

```
const nums = [2, 3, 6, 6, 5];

function getSecondLargest(nums) {
var firstLargest = nums[0];
var secondLargest = nums[0];

for(var i = 1; i < nums.length; i++){
    if (nums[i] > secondLargest){
        secondLargest = firstLargest;
        firstLargest = nums[i];
     }

    else if ((secondLargest === nums[i]) || (firstLargest === nums[i])){
        delete nums[I];

     }
    else{
        nums[i] = secondLargest;    
    }

}
return secondLargest;
```

}
console.log(getSecondLargest(nums));

Comment: Your definition of *second largest* is rather unusual.

Comment: So if a dupe than do not add it...

Comment: What would be the expected return value for an Array that is empty `nums=[]`, has only one value `nums=[5]` or contains only one kind of number `nums=[5,5,5,5,5]`?

Answer (score 1):

Just need to test for equals when evaluating secondLargest.

```js
const nums = [2, 3, 6, 6, 5];

function getSecondLargest(nums) {
  var largest = 0;
  var secondLargest = 0;

  nums.forEach(n => {
    if (n > largest ) {
      secondLargest = largest;
      largest = n;
      
    } else if ( n > secondLargest && n !== largest ){
      secondLargest = n;
    }
  });

  return secondLargest;

}

console.log(getSecondLargest(nums));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deduplicate items in an array, an easy way is to convert it into a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set): `new Set(array)`, and then, if required, create a new array from it: `Array.from(set)`. Putting everything together: `Array.from(new Set(array))`.

Now, another way of getting the second largest number from a given array could be to:

1. remove any duplicates;
2. sort the array;
3. get the second last value;

Something like the following:

```
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
  return Array.from(new Set(nums)).sort().slice(-2)[0]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a function I use to get the distinct items in an array, if you then sort this distinct list the second largest will be second item in the list.

```js
const nums = [2, 3, 6, 6, 5];

const distinct = (array) =>
  array
    ? array.reduce((results, item) => {
        if (!results.some((i) => i === item)) {
          results.push(item);
        }
        return results;
      }, [])
    : array;

const getSecondLargest = array => array && array.length >= 2 ? distinct(array).sort((a,b) => b - a)[1] : undefined;

console.log(getSecondLargest(nums));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first `filter` the array so you are left with an array containing only distinct values. Next you can the filtered array, `sort` it, and `return` the number at the second index of the sorted array:

```js
const a = [2, 3, 6, 6, 5];
const b = [5, 4, 2, 1, 3];
const c = [10, 12, 11, 9, 10];
const d = [8, 14, 7, 2, 1, 11, 18, 7, 4];

function getSecondLargest(arr) {
  const filtered = arr.reduce((accum, el) => {
    if (accum.indexOf(el) === -1) {
      accum.push(el);
    }
    return accum;
  }, []);
  const sorted = filtered.sort((a, b) => b - a);
  return sorted[1];
}

console.log(getSecondLargest(a)); //should return 5
console.log(getSecondLargest(b)); //should return 4
console.log(getSecondLargest(c)); //should return 11
console.log(getSecondLargest(d)); //should return 14
```